# função move_uploaded_file

Tags: php

Estou tendo dificuldade para fazer múltiplos uploados,no comando move_uploaded_file ele está enviando somente um.

```
   foreach ($imagem['name'] as $key => $fotos) {

                    if (isset($tipoAlbum)) {

                      $dados->setAlbum($tipoAlbum);

                          if (!file_exists($tipoAlbum)) {

                              @mkdir("album/" . $dados->getAlbum());

                                 echo $imagem['tmp_name'][$key];
                                echo $fotos; 
                              $t = $imagem['tmp_name'][$key];


                              move_uploaded_file($t, "album/" . $dados->getAlbum() . "/" . $dados->getImagem());

                          }

                    }

            }
```

Alguém pode me dar uma dica?

Comment: O que são todas essas variáveis? De onde vem e como é definido `$dados`? Está tomando os devidos cuidados para que cada imagem tenha um nome único? Pois se o nome não variar, os arquivos serão sobrescritos e apenas o último existirá.

Comment: $dados é um objeto da outra class que serve só pra insert,select e também tem get e set como extends e ótima dica vou colocar pra não sobrescrever...

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema segue o código a baixo

```
 // Busca os dados para o envio da imagem ao servidor.
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($imagem['name']); $i++) { 

        // Verifica se o arquivo já existe no servidor.
        if (!file_exists("album/".$dados->getAlbum()."/".$imagem['name'][$i])) {
    // o mkdir coloquei em outro lugar          
          // Move para o servidor
            move_uploaded_file($imagem['tmp_name'][$i], "album/".$dados->getAlbum()."/".$imagem['name'][$i]); 

        }

      }
```

Comment: O problema, então, era mesmo o conflito de nomes?

Comment: Isso mesmo, como você disse, ele estavá copiando os nome das imagens  e só enviava um arquivo